# SQL Server poor handling of date formatting

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

Why in most programming languages can I do something relatively intuitive like `format(mydate, "dd/mm/yyyy")` or `mydate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` but in SQL Server I have to remember some arbitrary number code such as 101 or 112 e.g.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Every time I need to format a date in TSQL I have to google it, it is simply impossible to remember unless you use the same one every day.

Is there a reason for this or another way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Formatting data for display should, as a rule, be left to application code and not handled in the database.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2012 onwards you can use the `FORMAT` function:

`select format(getdate(),'yyyyMMdd')`

Will returns `20161025`

Or if you want to go crazy:

`select format(getdate(),'yyyy/MM-dd')`

Will return `2016/10-25`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using 2008. Guess it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Depending on your needs, FORMAT() isn't an exact replacement of CONVERT() with the style parameter. CONVERT() with certain style parameters is deterministic whereas FORMAT() is nondeterministic, so you cannot use it in a persisted computed column.